# D3 Map XML Polygon ids to JSON data

Tags: d3.js, css-selectors

I have an [svg/xml file](https://github.com/gangrel11/samplefiles/blob/main/house.svg?short_path=5ee8cc1) that I'm loading into d3 using `d3.xml(...)`

This is the [output](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gangrel11/samplefiles/main/house.svg) of the SVG

I also have a small JSON dataset

```
const data = [{
    "id": "polygon5256", //roof
    "value": 39.5
  },
  {
    "id": "polygon1628",  //grass
    "value": 3.93
  },
  {
    "id": "polygon5254", //left wall
    "value": 3.14
  },
  {
    "id": "path5894", //door step
    "value": 20.98
  }
]
```

I'm trying to join the id's from the JSON dataset to the respective id's (polygons and paths) in the XML data. Do you know how I could also limit the selectable paths/polygons to only those that are in the JSON data? So only the available IDs will be affected by the mouse events?

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/mguhnr6b/72/)

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle you have `d3.select('#polygon5256')` but you can add events to any polygon with [`selectAll`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selectAll) and a different CSS selector:

```
d3.selectAll("svg polygon")
```

You want `path` too (for the door step) so the CSS selector you need is:

```
d3.selectAll("svg polygon, svg path")
```

In the handler you can get the `id` of the polygon with (since you use d3 v5.9.2):

```
d3.event.target.id
```

*Note that if you're using a later version of the D3 library this handling will need to change (see [D3 v6 changes](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide#events))*

I've changed your fiddle to have a single visible `div` where the mouseover and mouseout handlers just populate labelling if available in `data` or clear the text.

Working example:

```js
const data = [
  { "id": "polygon5256", "value": 39.5 }, // roof
  { "id": "polygon1628", "value": 3.93 }, // grass
  { "id": "polygon5254", "value": 3.14 }, // left wall
  { "id": "path5894", "value": 20.98 } // door step
];


// just make one visible div and leave text till later
const tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "visible");

const svgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gangrel11/samplefiles/main/house.svg";
d3.xml(svgUrl).then(render);

// on render set an event for any polygon of the svg
function render(data) {

  d3.select("body").node().append(data.documentElement)
  d3.selectAll("svg polygon, svg path")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
    
}

// set the text of the div if it's in the data set
function mouseover(d) {
  const id = d3.event.target.id;
  const obj = data.find(item => item.id === id);
  const text = obj ? `${id} - ${obj.value}` : "";
  tooltip.text(text);
  d3.select(`#${id}`).style("opacity", 0.5);
}

// clear the text of the div
function mouseout(d) {
  const id = d3.event.target.id;
  tooltip.text("");
  d3.select(`#${id}`).style("opacity", 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

### Edit

If you want to limit the paths/polygons to only those that are in the JSON data you can swap out this:

```
function render(data) {

  d3.select("body").node().append(data.documentElement)
  d3.selectAll("svg polygon, svg path")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
    
}
```

For this (note the function signature of `render` has to change as we refer to `data` array within the function):

```
function render(svg) {

  // add svg
  d3.select("body").node().append(svg.documentElement)
  
  // add events for ids  
  const ids = data.map(d => d.id);
  ids.forEach(id => d3.select(`#${id}`)
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
  );
  
}
```

Working example:

```js
const data = [
  { "id": "polygon5256", "value": 39.5 }, // roof
  { "id": "polygon1628", "value": 3.93 }, // grass
  { "id": "polygon5254", "value": 3.14 }, // left wall
  { "id": "path5894", "value": 20.98 } // door step
];

// just make one visible div and leave text till later
const tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .style("visibility", "visible");

// load external svg and render
const svgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gangrel11/samplefiles/main/house.svg";
d3.xml(svgUrl).then(render);

// on render set an event for anything with an id within data
function render(svg) {

  // add svg
  d3.select("body").node().append(svg.documentElement)
  
  // add events for ids  
  const ids = data.map(d => d.id);
  ids.forEach(id => d3.select(`#${id}`)
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
  );
  
}

// set the text of the div if it's in the data set
function mouseover(d) {
  const id = d3.event.target.id;
  const obj = data.find(item => item.id === id);
  const text = obj ? `${id} - ${obj.value}` : "";
  tooltip.text(text);
  d3.select(`#${id}`).style("opacity", 0.5);
}

// clear the text of the div
function mouseout(d) {
  const id = d3.event.target.id;
  tooltip.text("");
  d3.select(`#${id}`).style("opacity", 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks again Robin. Question... Do you know how I could also limit the selectable paths/polygons to only those that are in the JSON data?  So only the available IDs will be affected by the mouse events?

Comment: @Gangrel see my edit please

Comment: Thanks so much. However, do you know why I might be getting an "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.map is not a function
    at render (index.html:46:18)" error within jsfiddle?

Seems to be in relation to the line "const ids = data.map(d => d.id);" ?

See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/mguhnr6b/76/

Comment: @Gangrel - sure, it's because data is both the array and the argument passed to render. Change it to like `function render(svg) {...` and then also `d3.select("body").node().append(svg.documentElement)`